# My SSI #exec output is getting truncated

Tags: apache, ssi

I am using Apache's (2.4) include_module to build some simple web pages to output the status of the system it is running on.   For example one page has the HTML fragment:

```
                <pre>
<!--#exec cmd="ps ax" -->
                </pre>
```

Which should, and does, put the output of the **ps** command on the page.   However it is a fairly large list and the last part of it gets cut off.  The part that does get displayed is about 9000 characters long.

I can't find any documentation about an output limitation for the SSI commands.  Can someone advise me what is going on here?

UPDATE: To see what the "limit" was I changed the command to **cat joonk.txt** and filled that file with a large amount of text.   There seems to be no limit
to how much text you can output and it displays.

However I found that the output is content sensitive.  The **ps** command includes the output:

```
4306 tty7     S<s+   9:59 /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp :0 -auth /tmp/serverauth.sjfX0yR4qj
```

and the output always stops after the "S".  The "<" and subsequent characters don't output.  This is true regardless of whether it is output by the **ps** command or the **cat** command.   So it looks like the start of an XML/HTML tag.

So I am changing my question -- how do I stop the included text from being interpreted?  The **pre** tag apparently doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used to this was to filter the output to escape the HTML special characters.  So instead of

```
ps ax
```

I use

```
ps ax | sed -e 's~&~\&amp;~g' -e 's~<~\&lt;~g'  -e  's~>~\&gt;~g’
```

Footnote: It seems that there was the **xmp** tag that does this and is supported by all browsers but deprecated in the standards.